# Quadratic expression problem involving sides of a triangle

Tags: inequality, quadratics

If $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle where $a\neq b\neq c$ and $\lambda \in R$, if roots of the equation $x^{2} + 2\lgroup a+b+c\rgroup x + 3\lambda\lgroup ab+bc+ca\rgroup =0$ are real, then what is the range of $\lambda$?

Comment: I have tried solving the inequality where discriminant of the equation greater than or equal to 0, but i am unable to find a proper relation for lambda

Comment: You say you've gotten as far as Bush took it, but you didn't show that work. You said in a comment to Bush that he didn't take it far enough. You need to be clearer about what you are looking for, then.

Comment: ok, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we incorporate the triangle restriction using the substitution $a = u+v, b = v+w, c = w+u$, where $u, v, w$ are now distinct positive reals.

So the quadratic we want to have real roots is now:
$$x^2+4(u+v+w)x+3\lambda(u^2+v^2+w^2+3uv+3vw+3wu)$$

The condition for real roots is that the discriminant is non-negative, so we need to have for any allowable choice of $u, v, w$:
$$4(u+v+w)^2 \ge 3\lambda(u^2+v^2+w^2+3uv+3vw+3wu)$$
$$\implies 4(u+v+w)^2 \ge 3\lambda\left((u+v+w)^2+(uv+vw+wu)\right)$$
$$\implies \frac43\frac{(u+v+w)^2}{(u+v+w)^2+(uv+vw+wu)} \ge \lambda$$

So we need to find the maximum possible value for the LHS to get the full range of $\lambda$.
$$\frac43\frac{(u+v+w)^2}{(u+v+w)^2+(uv+vw+wu)}=\frac43\frac1{1+\frac{uv+vw+wu}{(u+v+w)^2}} < \frac43$$
As if $(u, v) \to (0, 1)$, then $uv+vw+wu \to w$ and $(u+v+w) \to (1+w)^2$ so the ratio can be made as small as desired by taking sufficiently large $w$.

Hence the possible range of $\lambda$ is $(-\infty, \frac43)$.

Answer (score 1):

From the quadratic formula $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ from your formula we have $$a=1,b=2(a+b+c),c=3\lambda (ab+bc+ca)$$ Subbing in $$x= \frac{-2(a+b+c) \pm \sqrt{(2(a+b+c))^2-12\lambda (ab+bc+ca)}}{2}$$ The radical is what deterimines if we will have real roots, meaning that we need $$(2(a+b+c))^2-12\lambda (ab+bc+ca) \ge 0\\\lambda \le\frac {(a+b+c)^2}{3(ab+bc+ca)}$$ This will give you a range of $$R(\lambda)=(- \infty, \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{3(ab+bc+ca)}]$$

Comment: I have done it this far, but what I need is a specific range i.e. range specified by values

Comment: What do you mean by range specified by values?

Comment: this question is mcq type. it comes with 4 options 4/3, 5/3, (1/3, 5/3), (4/3, 5/3). The answer is among these options

Comment: If you assume $a+b \ge c$ (because they are unequal sides of a triangle), then that must restrict the range a little more.

Comment: @Jim that's a strange inequality. From the question you may assume without loss of generality that $a>b>c>0$ (assuming we are ignoring degenerate cases). I don't see what the addition inequality offers there.